# name.startsWith generate TS(2532)

Tags: typescript, tsx, startswith

If `name` is a var with the string "test_word"

```
hWriteResult.lowest ? name === ('test_word')?  hWriteResult.lowest*2 : hWriteResult.lowest
```

then it checks on `'test_word'`

When I try to use:

```
hWriteResult.lowest ? name.startsWith === ('test')?  hWriteResult.lowest*2  : hWriteResult.lowest
```

I get an error at:      `name.startsWith === ('test')`.

```
(local var) name: string | undefined
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
This condition will always return 'false' since the types '(searchString: string, position?: number | undefined) => boolean' and 'string' have no overlap.ts(2367)
```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: what does this have to do with java and xml?

Comment: `hWriteResult.lowest ? name?.startsWith === ('test')?  hWriteResult.lowest*2  : hWriteResult.lowest`
you need to add `?` after name because it can be undefined

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing whether the `name` value `startsWtih` a value, pass it as a parameter to the [`startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) function:

```
name.startsWith('test')
```

which will return a boolean.

https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-startswith-method-in-typescript